# FIWARE Orion Context Broker API V2 - accumulator-server.py

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

When I try to create a subscription using the next query:

```
curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
{
   "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
   "subject": {
     "entities": [
       {
         "id": "Room10",
         "type": "Room"
       }
     ],
     "condition": {
       "attrs": ["pressure"]
     }
   },
   "notification": {
     "http": {
       "url": "http://localhost:1028/publish"
     },
     "attrs": ["temperature"]
   },
   "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
   "throttling": 5
}
EOF
```

An error occurs:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 1026 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... connected
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 1026 (#0)
> POST /v2/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:1026
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 376
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 72
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Thu, 24 May 2018 07:38:32 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
{"error":"BadRequest","description":"no condition attributes specified"}
```

However, if I make the query using the V1 of the API all work right. I do not know why. Please help me!

Comment: It is really strange, because the error message says "no condition attributes specified" and this is specified in your JSON. Are you really sure you are using the correct JSON format (without any typo)?

Comment: Which Orion version are you using? i.e. output of `contextBroker --version`.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your same request with a recent Orion version (1.13.0 + some not yet released stuff only in master branch at the present moment) and it works:

```
$ curl -v localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<EOF
> {
>    "description": "A subscription to get info about Room1",
>    "subject": {
>      "entities": [
>        {
>          "id": "Room10",
>          "type": "Room"
>        }
>      ],
>      "condition": {
>        "attrs": ["pressure"]
>      }
>    },
>    "notification": {
>      "http": {
>        "url": "http://localhost:1028/publish"
>      },
>      "attrs": ["temperature"]
>    },
>    "expires": "2040-01-01T14:00:00.00Z",
>    "throttling": 5
> }
> EOF
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 1026 (#0)
> POST /v2/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: localhost:1026
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 400
> 
* upload completely sent off: 400 out of 400 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: /v2/subscriptions/5b082dc2c17960f8773dd74d
< Fiware-Correlator: 8dd38278-6031-11e8-b6dc-000c29173617
< Date: Fri, 25 May 2018 15:37:38 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution : The Server accumulator-server.py is not showing message as per documentation .
In Docker where your orion is running , you should use subscriber url is ipv6 not locahost . Because outside docker , localhost will not be notified .

This is working as per the subscription

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3570#issuecomment-1007966810